# PHPMailer mailed-by header

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Im using PHPMailer for sending emails. But for some reason its always go to spams box..

Google say the email is missing **mailed-by header**.

The question is how do i add the additional header using PHPMailer?

```
current code:
function sendMail($mail, $arr) {
    $mail->AddAddress($arr['toEmail'], $arr['toName']);
    $mail->SetFrom($arr['fromEmail'], $arr['fromName']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($replyEmail, $replyName);
    $mail->Subject = trim($arr['subject']);
    $mail->addCustomHeader('mailed-by: mydomain.com'); <-- didnt work.
    $mail->MsgHTML( trim($arr['content']) );
    $mail->IsHTML(true); 
    $mail->Send();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be setting the `Mail-By` header as far as I can see. It's set by the `Mail Transfer Agent (MTA)` based off the from address. This could be a mail server setup issue. Have you tried sending mail with the php `mail` command?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try: `$mail->Hostname` according to this [documentation](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=properties).

Comment: thanks.. its adding now. but for some reason google mark it as spam? any idea?

Comment: Maybe it's your content? Try sending an email with just a sentence and no anchor tags.

Answer (score -1):

Already tried this?:

```
$mail->Host = "mydomain.com";
```